# Heapdump creation in openshift (OCP 3.11)

Tags: out-of-memory, openshift, heap-dump

I have setup the environment in my OC config maps for generating the heap dump. However, whenever there is a OOM error, it terminated the pod and restarted the container. Please assist me, how can i get the heap dump now.

sample reference of my configuration - -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=dump123.hprof

Answer (score 0):

Pod is an ephemeral environment. Everything in the Pod is cleared when the container is down. You need to use Persistent Storage to store file, core and so on.

If you have a nfs storage, you can use it to create PV and PVC. And then, you need to mount it on the Pod.

See the following documentation.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.11/html-single/configuring_clusters/index#overview-18